# 3d structure in android application

Tags: android, 3d

So, for a personal project, I'm trying to make an app that helps newcomers get used to the school quickly. And for one section of it, I'm trying to build a 3D Structure, in a shape of my school campus, with lables incidating where the rooms are, so when the using searches for specific rooms, they can easily find it. So, It would be like from one activity, when I click a button, it opens a new activity with a search bar on the top, and the rest of the screen a 3d image people can navigate through. What's a way I can accomplish this?

I know that the structure part can be accomplished with Unity, which I haven't learned but have an idea of what it is, but I don't know how to build the rest of the app with Unity.. So..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to start with designing the model (structure) in some-kind of modeling program, Maya, 3DS Max, Cinema 4D, Blender, etc... (Personally I recommend using Blender since it's free and open source). Then you would want to export it to some 3D model format, I recommend using .obj since it is very human-readable and easy to parse on your own, but you can use some other format and parse it using a library.

Now comes the more difficult part and it's to render the loaded model onto the screen. This can be accomplished with OpenGL ES or a more highlevel library which can abstract it for you. If you're not familiar with OpenGL ES or OpenGL in general, I wouldn't recommend using it since it may take some time to learn. There are few libraries out there which can render 3D models pretty easily. Now you should probably create some-kind of a controllable camera as well so you can use it to navigate through the model.

This maybe looks like a lot of work but if you already familiar with computer 3D graphics it can ease it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can make a 3d model of your school using [Blender](http://www.blender.org) (which is a free tool, but will almost certainly be a lot of work). Export the model as a mesh which you can insert into your app as an asset or resource. Read the resource and present it using (probably) opengl.  This is a *SUPER* high level view, in actual fact there's quite a lot of work in each stage. Some third party libraries can make it a little easier, but it will still be a big job. I personally like [libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) for abstracting the pain of opengl, but that's just my personal opinion.

It's a big job, but would be *super cool* .. good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot. Do you know any projects I could refer to that has a similar structure?

Comment: Actually there are some samples in the libgdx website that are kind-of similar.. more importantly they are actual Android applications, so it kind of helps demonstrate the bits in between.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting off with building the structure in a program like Blender, Maja or 3ds Max. You can export your projects from those programs to pretty much any game engine and it makes more sense to build things in one of those programs.

Once you're done with that you can choose which engine you want to use to add the search function, if unity or Unreal or whatever but either way you're going to need to make yourself familiar with java or c to add the search function.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use blueprints of building if available, it will save you a loads of nerves. Use it as a material texture and place it on a plane polygon to get a good lining helper.

If you do use Unity for development then try Maya for polygonal modeling. At least they are looking similar to each other whereas 3DSMax is always a mind f*cking experience.